# Big data(spark sql and spark dataframes connection)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql, apache-spark-dataset

I am new to big data platform. Could you please let me know the different ways:
1)how do we connect to spark for Spark sql?
2)how do we connect to sparrk for spark dataframes or datasets?

for hive,we connect through unix with beeline and if we have sql tool like: teradata we have to connect to hive through odbc with hive driver installed.

What about connecting to spark sql and spark dataframes or datasets?

Also if any one could provide me a good link or resource for a newbie like me to understand the concepts, commands and its use easily.That would really be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

To use spark sql with SQL like querying you can simply type

```
spark-sql --master yarn # when you are testing on a Hadoop cluster
```

or

```
spark-sql --master local[2]   # when you are testing on local machine
```

and you can simply run all queries that you run on the `beeline>` shell in the `spark-sql>` shell.

Alternatively, if you wish to simply test some scala code:

```
spark-shell --master yarn # on cluster
```

or

```
spark-shell --master local[2] # on Local setup
```

Answer (score 0):

spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("wordCount").getOrCreate()

spark.sql("select * from table_name").show()

you can refer below link

https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/8223668471254563/888847798980585/528896120252697/latest.html

Comment: The link is about reading CSV from DBFS. It does not explain anything about connection to Spark and running Spark SQL. Please modify your answer to make corrections.